# "Fixed query_filter error" occurs in postfix

Tags: postfix

I  management accounts with postfix 2.5+openLDAP. 
and I manage the mailing list by LDAP too.

but this error occured in /var/log/mail.log
    warning: dict_ldap_open: /etc/postfix/ldapml: Fixed query_filter (&(objectClass=organizationalPerson))

In particular does not have any problem, but I want to delete this log. 
How to remove this errors?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad ldap filter rule. This query will always return the same answer.

We can help if you post your rules here. (/etc/postfix/ldapml)
And it can also help if you post the output of

> postconf -n

too.